# Low bound of Dirichlet eta function

Tags: special-functions, analytic-number-theory

every one. Suppose that $\eta(s)$ is Dirichlet eta function, I may find a low bound of this function, namely

$\eta(2n)>\frac{2^{2n-1}-2}{2^{2n-1}-1}$

with $n>1$ and $n$ is a integer.
But is this true? can somebody **prove** or **disprove** it?

Comment: This is formula (3.8) in Lemma 1 of the paper **Numerical calculation of the Riemann zeta function at odd integer arguments: A direct formula method** by  Qiang Luo and Zhidan Wang, available from http://arxiv.org/abs/1404.7221. They claim that it is true for $n\ge 1$, but they give no proof: *Those two inequalities are quite new to the authors because we haven’t seen them in any literature or monograph. However, we are not intended to give the details here since the demonstration is rather elementary.*

Answer (score 0):

Well, in fact, one can use the fact that

$1+\frac{1}{2^x}+\int_2^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^x}dx>\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^x}>1+\frac{1}{2^x}+\int_3^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^x}dx$.

The inequality chain gives a stronger form.